# typedef T Type::* syntax

Tags: c++, syntax

I need help to understand the following (simplified) code snipped:

```
template < typename R >
struct Variable
{
    typedef VariableBaseTable< R >  BaseType;
    typedef R BaseType::*            VarType; //!

    template < typename Type >
    R & operator()(Type * obj) const
    {
        return (reinterpret_cast< ObjType >(obj))->*(_variable); //!
    }
    // more stuff follows
}
```

The two lines I need help understanding are marked with a `//!` in the end.

I could not understand what the `R BaseType::*` is defining. In particular, how the `::*` syntax works.

In the second marked line, I could not understand the syntax `obj->*(_var)`, I can see that obj is being dereferenced, but what the `*` is doing there right after it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef R BaseType::* VarType;
```

is a type alias which defines `VarType` as a pointer-to-member-of-`BaseType` of type `R`. In the second marked line, you are accessing the field `_variable` via the [pointer-to-member access operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_pointer-to-member_access_operators) `->*`, see e.g. [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members) for more details about the syntax and some examples.